# How to evaluate Python code blocks with pipenv instead of system environment?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python

I'm trying to use org-mode as an alternative to Jupyter. I'm able to evaluate code blocks with system environment by doing `C-c C-c` on blocks, but I don't know how to evaluate it through pipenv environment. I installed and configured [pipenv.el](https://github.com/pwalsh/pipenv.el) but the documentation doesn't say how to evaluate code blocks with it.

Comment: Thank's @NickD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I configured `pipenv` package after installing it:

```
(use-package pipenv
  :hook (python-mode . pipenv-mode)
  :commands (pipenv-mode
         pipenv-activate
         pipenv-run))
```

When you open a buffer with python code, if you want the code to be ran by pipenv you have to activate pipenv first by doing `M-x pipenv-activate` once.